# scipy minimize gives a hess_inv that is completely different from inv(statmodel.approx_hess)

Tags: standard-error, fisher-information, hessian

I'm fitting a model with MLE using `scipy.minimize` (method BFGS). I want to have the hessian to compute its inverse and retrieve the standard error of each parameter.

The result of `minimize` contains one approximation of the inverse hessian matrix in `res.hess_inv`. To cross-check with other methods, I computed the hessian inverse using statmodel `approx_hess` and then applying `np.linalg.inv`. It gives a completely different matrix (with some diagonal elements that have up to 2 order of magnitude difference)

Finally, I decided to compute the hessian myself since it looks like I can't cross-check the result of the functions above :

```
def approx_hessian(x, f, eps=1e-5, only_diag=False) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Computes an approximation of the Hessian matrix of a function using the finite difference method.

    Parameters:
    x (array-like): The point at which to compute the Hessian matrix.
    f (callable): The function to compute the Hessian of.
                  The function should take an array-like object as input and return a scalar.
    epsilon (float, optional): The step size for the finite difference method.

    Returns:
    hessian (ndarray): An approximation of the Hessian matrix of func at x.
    """
    n = len(x)
    hessian = np.zeros((n, n))

    # Compute the off-diagonal elements
    if not only_diag:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j or i < j:
                    continue # the hessian is symmetrical, so we can compute only half of it
                p1 = x.copy()
                p1[i] += eps
                p1[j] += eps

                p2 = x.copy()
                p2[i] += eps
                p2[j] -= eps

                p3 = x.copy()
                p3[i] -= eps
                p3[j] += eps

                p4 = x.copy()
                p4[i] -= eps
                p4[j] -= eps

                hessian[i][j] = (f(p1) - f(p2) - f(p3) + f(p4)) / (4 * eps ** 2)
    hessian = hessian + hessian.transpose()  # fill the element under the diagonal with the same numbers

    # compute diagonal elements
    for i in range(n):
        p_forward = x.copy()
        p_forward[i] += eps

        p_backward = x.copy()
        p_backward[i] -= eps

        hessian[i][i] = (f(p_forward) - 2 * f(x) + f(p_backward)) / (eps ** 2)

    return hessian
```

I test my implementation by computing manually double derivatives on a simple function having 3 parameters :

```
def test_approx_hessian(self):
    # example taken from https://www.allmath.com/hessian-matrix-calculator.php
    def fn(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
        x, y, z = params
        return 2 * y * x ** 4 + 2 * y ** 3 + 2 * x * z ** 3

    def expected_hessian(p: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        x, y, z = p
        return np.array([
            [24 * x ** 2 * y, 8 * x ** 3, 6 * z ** 2],
            [8 * x ** 3, 12 * y, 0],
            [6 * z ** 2, 0, 12 * x * z],
        ])

    point = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
    hessian_expected = expected_hessian(point)
    hessian_approx = approx_hessian(point, fn)
    self.assertTrue(np.allclose(hessian_expected, hessian_approx, atol=1e-4))
```

This test passes, so I believe my function works.

However when I compute the hessian inverse using my implementation, it gives a matrix that is not only still completely different from the 2 others, but also with diagonal elements that are negative ... (while they should be variances, so the diagonal elements are supposed to be positive as far as I know)

Are maths doing me a prank ? What am I doing wrong ?  What function should I "trust" to have finally a standard error of my parameters ?

Comment: couple things going on here: 1) you will only have positive variances if the Hessian is positive definite. If you have truly found on optimum, the hessian will be positive definite there. In high-dimensional problems, it is very easy to find approximate optima which don't actually have a positive definite hessian. in your final code block, it seems like you're evaluating the hessian at an arbitrary point. There is no reason to expect this to be positive definite. 2) BFGS only approximates the Hessian after many many runs, and only if the Hessian is positive definite at the stationary point...

Comment: ..., one advantage about the BFGS approximation is that it will always be positive definite, unlike the Hessian. So the advantage of the BFGS approximation is that it will always give positive variances. However, the disadvantage is that you're not directly controlling the approximation error.

Comment: can you check if the hessian from approx_hess is positive definite? To do this, compute its eigendecomp and see if any eigenvalues are negative.

Comment: and finally, regarding " What function should I "trust" to have finally a standard error of my parameters ?" I would not trust any code not validated by simulation study (with known parameters where you can empirically evaluate the purported standard errors), and even then, we would still "trust but verify".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After inspecting all 3 matrixes given respectively by minimize, statmodel, and my implem, I see that practically all diagonal element are not that far ("only" 2 times difference). However, 1 element of the diagonal of my 12*12 matrix is very different for the 3 matrixes. minimize gives 1.05, statmodel gives 230, and my implem. gives -2. This particular element prevents me from having a standard error for the parameter best estimate which is 30. Indeed, depending on the hessian I respectively: accept H0, reject H0, or cannot make any choice since -2 is negative

Comment: regarding the eigenvalues, my implementation shows one negative eigenvalue, not the 2 other functions ..

Comment: to see whether that eigenvalue is "really" negative, see if you can move from the optimum along the associated eigenvector (in either direction). In math notation, if your optimal solution is $x$ and the eigenvector associated with the negative eigenvalue is $u$, then try $f(x+\lambda u)$ for $\lambda \in [-100,-10,-1,-0.1,\ldots,-1e-10,1e-10,1e-9,\ldots,0.1,1,100]$. Then see if any of those beats $f(x)$ substantially.

Comment: In my experience though, the Hessian approximation to the sampling covariance works best with convex likelihoods, and can be unreliable otherwise (as in your case). You may wish to use bootstrapping or Bayes instead.

Comment: Likelihood is always concave at optimum right ? Since the curvature needs to locally "decelerate" to reach an optimum ? By bootstrapping you mean resampling randomly until I have a positive hessian ?

Comment: Regarding your comment on eigenvectors, if I understand correctly, a not positive definite hessian happens if I can find a better estimate (with lower loss), when I move the current estimate solution along the eigen vector is that right ?

Comment: (Just trying to understand intuitively, visually, what corresponds to a hessian not positive definite)

Comment: "Likelihood is always concave at optimum right" yes, theoretically. But in practice, when optimizing nonconvex likelihoods in higher dimensional spaces using numerical methods, the stationary points we end up at tend not to be strict optima, but rather saddle points wrt at least some of the input directions. And yes that's right regarding the positive definite hessian; google "saddle point" to see visually what's going on. (This is all assuming that the eigenval is indeed negative, which we're not 100% sure about.)

Comment: and no, by bootstrapping, I mean resampling, computing an MLE (and no hessian), and repeating. Then, calculating empirical standard error on the bootstrapped sample.

Comment: Indeed some of the eigen values were negative which means that I ended up in saddle point. 
I posted another question related to it, if you want to have a look https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/613493/how-to-compare-2-estimates-from-a-model-fitted-by-mle-when-the-covariance-of-the
Thank you for your time

Comment: I've looked at your new question. I still really think that bootstrapping is the way to go here.

Comment: Problem is that in my case, one MLE fitting last 2 hours for 15k points.. so if I were to resample with this same sample size and try several samples it could potentially take days before I get the variance. Maybe I should analyse if the MLE estimator variance converges to the same distribution as n -> infinity ? This way I could maybe take much smaller samples and average the variances from all of them, whenever they are available (hess_inv definite positive) ?

Comment: I see empiracally though that the lesser is the sample size, the higher is the probability to have non definite positive hess_inv

Comment: I see. That makes things much more interesting :) I think solving this problem is nontrivial, and you may wish to seek an academic statistical collaborator (if you're in academia) or a statistical consultant (if you're in industry/gov't) rather than an answer on a site like CV.

Comment: Indeed this is more complex than what I expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **not** use the output from BFGS as the true inverse of the hessian.

The reason for this is that BFGS does not approximate the hessian based on the current rate of change of the derivatives of the target function. Rather, it builds up a useful approximation by tracking the change of the first derivative at each state of the optimization algorithm. I believe it also uses some regularization to keep the step sizes in check. Note that without regularization, you can't have an invertable Hessian based on solely first order differences of the gradient if you've got less steps than parameters of your model.

This means, at best, you have something like the inverse of the weighted average of the changes of the first derivative through the different iterations of your algorithm, which may be very different than the inverse of the Hessian at the MLE. At worst, you have a matrix that's heavily regularized as to make sure that your next step isn't too large, where the regularization has nothing to do with the uncertainty of the parameters of your model.

Wikipedia [cautions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm) about this issue, but I think they understate it:

> In statistical estimation problems (such as maximum likelihood or Bayesian inference), credible intervals or confidence intervals for the solution can be estimated from the inverse of the final Hessian matrix[citation needed]. However, these quantities are technically defined by the true Hessian matrix, and the BFGS approximation may not converge to the true Hessian matrix

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understand in short BFGS performs a rough and inconsistent approximation of the matrix that doesn't necessarily converges toward the real one. So one should use statmodel approx_hessian instead after a MLE to retrieve standard error I guess ?

Comment: Yep. As a small caveat, usually when we use BFGS we have a closed form solution for the gradient, but maybe not the hessian. It's usually a faster to estimate the hessian off first order differences of the gradient than to estimate it from second order differences of the target function as is done in approx_hessian, but I would only worry about this if speed is a significant issue and the parameter space is moderately sized (i.e. >10).

Comment: All right in my case computing the hessian itself is not a big deal (1 minute for 1500 observations in a 12 parameters space) but then the problem is : how do I deal with negative element of the hessian inverse diagonal ? There are not variance so I can't retrieve any standard error from them ?

Comment: If the hessian is not invertible, it means the likelihood is not well behaved and unfortunately MLE theory cannot be used to derive standard errors. Sometimes this issue will go away simply by having more data if that's available. In other cases, you can try to reparameterize the model so that the likelihood behaves better, i.e. reparameterize so that derivatives are more stable.