# How to compare 2 estimates from a model fitted by MLE when the covariance of the estimate can't be always estimated?

Tags: statistical-significance, likelihood-ratio, wald-test

I have one model, that I fit using MLE. In order to feel what could be a good initial guess for the fitting process, I try different arbitrary smartly chosen initial guess (not random) and report the final estimate for each of them, along with their associated loss (i.e., negative log-likelihood).

Now that I have this bench of estimate with their loss (from each of the initial guesses), I take the loss that is minimal, and I want to compare all other estimate to it. Despite we cannot really say that this estimate $\theta^*$ is really the best of the parameter space, let's assume that (because the parameter space is huge and my problem is too complicated to find an analytical solution)

When I compare the other estimates to that assumed best estimate $\theta^*$, I want to know what estimate is significantly different from $\theta^*$. Indeed, if the loss associated to $\theta^*$ is 850 and one other initial guess gives an estimate of loss 850.001, I don't want to discard it from the "good" initial guess that I want to retrieve in the end.

From what I see on the Internet, performing a paired t-test on these estimate is not appropriate in the context of MLE. I saw method like the Wald Test. I wanted to perform a Wald test with restricted subset of the parameter space $\Phi$ being $\{\theta^*\}$. However, in my case I cannot retrieve the covariance matrix at the estimate in all cases, because the FIM at estimate is often not definite positive (one eigen value < 0), which lead to negative variance in the hessian inverse, which is in the end not usable. And since the Wald test needs the covariance matrix of the tested estimate, I cannot use it for about 75% of my estimates (25% still have an covariance estimate from the FIM though)

Then I saw the log-likelihood ratio test, which only needs the likelihood of the 2 estimate that I have. However, I saw that this test measures the goodness of fit for *different* nested models: the chi-square distribution has $k$ degrees of freedom, $k$ being the difference between the number of parameter of each model. Since the models are the same in my case, I just want to compare 2 estimate from the same model, the chi-square distribution would have k=0, so it's not meant for my problem I guess.

What should I do to compare 2 estimates from the same model fitted by MLE, and see if there are significantly different, when the covariance matrix cannot be estimated from the FIM everytime ? Is it even possible ?  If not, what rule should I set to decide to discard or not one initial guess for my model ?

(Please note that I'm quite new to data science / statistics)